# passing unquoted criterion to count in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I'm writing a long script that takes a simple criterion to process meteorological data, such as counting the total days above 30 degrees per year, I just want to enter the criterion once, stored as an object, say:

```
var <- "V2 > 0"
```

to enter this at the top of the script; the problem is that when I pass it to

`count(criterion = var)`

it is being read as character and returns NaNs, i tried unquote(), as.name() which give no result, and as.factor() which gives a bad result,
a sample of my data:

```
station = structure(list(V1 = structure(1:10, .Label = c("18/06/1982", 
"19/06/1982", "20/06/1982", "21/06/1982", "22/06/1982", "23/06/1982", 
"24/06/1982", "25/06/1982", "26/06/1982", "27/06/1982"), class = "factor"), 
    V2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 3.5, 2.2, 0, 0, 1, 1.1)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

the code i'm trying to run (by replacing V2 > 0 with the object `var`):

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
station %>% mutate(V1=dmy(station$V1, tz="America/Mexico_City")) %>% 
  group_by(year(V1)) %>% count(criterion = V2 > 0 ) %>% filter(criterion == T)  %>% 
  colMeans(na.rm = T)
```

Comment: If you have `cond = quote(V2 > 0)`, then you can do `count(criterion = !! cond)` through new magic from the rlang package.

Comment: @eipi10 Looks answerworthy. I won't post since I don't know the semantics, only got there through trial and error.

Comment: good, it works, thanks for adding the lubridate package; can you post so i can mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an expression and `!!`:

```
cond = quo(V2 > 0)
station %>% mutate(V1=dmy(station$V1, tz="America/Mexico_City")) %>% 
  group_by(year(V1)) %>% count(criterion = !!cond ) %>% filter(criterion == T)  %>% 
  colMeans(na.rm = T)

#  year(V1) criterion         n 
#      1982         1         4
```

Comment: (I am not familiar with this syntax, so please edit where appropriate.)